# Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'function'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, store, redux-thunk

I have a react project using redux and fake API (https://reqres.in/). I want to get users from API using axios and redux-thunk in App component. But when I try this I see this error:

> Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'function'.You may need to add middleware to your store setup to handle dispatching other values, such as 'redux-thunk' to handle dispatching functions.

Here is my App component:

```
function App() {
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 const getUsers=()=>{
      
        // async action using redux-thunk
        return async function(dispatch){
         
            try{
            
            dispatch(GetUserRequest())
             const response= await axios.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
             
            
             dispatch(GetUserSuccess(response.data.data))
            }
            catch(er){
                dispatch(GetUserFail(er))
               
            }
        }
    }

useEffect(()=>{
   
   
    dispatch(getUsers())
    
  
  }
    
  ,[])
}
```

And here is my store:

```
import { usersReducer } from "./users/usersReducer";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
export const store=createStore(usersReducer,applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

And here is my reducer (usersReducer):

```
import {  GET_USER_FAIL, GET_USER_REQUEST, GET_USER_SUCCESS} from "./usersTypes"
const initialState={
     users:[],
     error:"",
     loading:true,
    
 }
export const usersReducer=(state=initialState,action)=>{
switch(action.type){
  case GET_USER_REQUEST:
        
        return {...state,users:[],error:"",loading:true}
      
       
      case GET_USER_SUCCESS:
         
        return {users:action.payload,
            error:"",loading:false}
      case GET_USER_FAIL:
        return {...state,users:[],error:action.payload,loading:false}
}
}
```

Types(usersType):

```
export const   GET_USER_SUCCESS="GET_USER_SUCCESS";
export const  GET_USER_FAIL="GET_USER_FAIL";
export const  GET_USER_REQUEST="GET_USER_REQUEST";
```

ActonCreators(usersActions):

```
import { GET_USER_REQUEST,GET_USER_SUCCESS,GET_USER_FAIL} from "./usersTypes"
export const GetUserRequest=()=>{
  return{type:GET_USER_REQUEST} 
}
export const GetUserSuccess=(data)=>{
   return{
       type:GET_USER_SUCCESS,
       payload:data
   }
}
export const GetUserFail=(error)=>{
    return{
        type:GET_USER_FAIL,
        payload:error,
    }  
}
}
```

And of course I've installed redux-thunk and redux and react-redux.

according to stackoverflow related questions and answers, there must be  some problems in action creators or applying middleware. But they seem perfect to me.